# How do I use the swipe gesture to remove cards within a recycleview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

How do I use the swipe gesture to remove cards from my recycle-view in the same way that it is done in Google-now etc. So far I've created the cardview application but it's removing cards via a swipe gesture which I'm having problems with. I haven't found a single tutorial or question answered on this website which could help.

Any help would be very much appreciated. My code is below.

**MyActivity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

        ContactAdapter ca = new ContactAdapter(createList(30));
        recList.setAdapter(ca);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private List<ContactInfo> createList(int size) {

        List<ContactInfo> result = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
        for (int i=1; i <= size; i++) {
            ContactInfo ci = new ContactInfo();
            ci.name = ContactInfo.NAME_PREFIX + i;
            ci.surname = ContactInfo.SURNAME_PREFIX + i;
            ci.email = ContactInfo.EMAIL_PREFIX + i + "@test.com";

            result.add(ci);

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**ContactInfo.java**

```
public class ContactInfo {
    protected String name;
    protected String surname;
    protected String email;


    protected static final String NAME_PREFIX = "Name_";
    protected static final String SURNAME_PREFIX = "Surname_";
    protected static final String EMAIL_PREFIX = "email_";
}
```

**ContactAdapter.java**

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

    private List<ContactInfo> contactList;

    public ContactAdapter(List<ContactInfo> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
        ContactInfo ci = contactList.get(i);
        contactViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);
        contactViewHolder.vSurname.setText(ci.surname);
        contactViewHolder.vEmail.setText(ci.email);
        contactViewHolder.vTitle.setText(ci.name + " " + ci.surname);
    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

            return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView vName;
        protected TextView vSurname;
        protected TextView vEmail;
        protected TextView vTitle;

        public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            vSurname = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);
            vEmail = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
            vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_my.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**card_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/bkg_card"
            android:text="contact det"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSurname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Surname"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txtName"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txtSurname"/>

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code (`ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` from Android support V7) to remove the cards from RecyclerView using swipe gesture

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
        contacts.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        ca.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoved(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int fromPos, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int toPos, int x, int y) {
        super.onMoved(recyclerView, viewHolder, fromPos, target, toPos, x, y);
    }
};

ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recList);
```